# Javascript: Write content to new page but keep same location

Tags: javascript

From a page I'm opening a new window via Javascript and then writing "my dynamic content" to it:

```
const win = window.open( "", "" );
win.document.documentElement.innerHTML = "my dynamic content";
```

The problem is that some of the references resources in the real "my dynamic content" are relative to the original page, for instance I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
```

Is there some way of preserving the location of the original page, whilst still being able to write the content to the new page? I tried the following, but this just uses the content from the `window.location` URL, overwriting "my dynamic content":

```
const win = window.open( window.location, "" );
...
```

Comment: Write a `<base>` element with the proper URL dynamically into the popup as well …? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: @CBroe That solved it!